# Exclude a Specific file to older Typescript version

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 11 and i have couple of libraries that are not compiling in TSC 4.0 as those are made specific for older versions. (And I don't have source code for those)

Given this case, I am wondering what can I do force TSC to use older version for this library?
Consider following package.json  ... I have 3 libraries A, B, C. Typescript compiler complaining about few stuff that have been changed in Latest Typescript version, that was working earlier in 3.8+ ..

If I downgrade from `"typescript": "4.0.5",` to  `"typescript": "3.8",` or  `"typescript": "3.9"`
Angular complains that it needs typescript version 4.0 and above....

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "11.0.5",
     ... 
     "lib-A": "file:folder-A",
     "lib-B": "file:folder-B",
     "lib-C": "file:folder-C"
}
```

Any suggestions to tackle this? I don't have source code of any of libraries ... :(

Comment: what kind of files do you have for those libs, js or ts?

Comment: I have .ts Files

Comment: confused what do you mean by "(And I don't have source code for those)"

Comment: If I would have source code (or js files) then I would have fixed the issue and converted the JS into .ts file... that is what I meant ...hope that clarifies